# JSF 2.2 Target Unreachable, identifier 'login' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have faced a problem which may be common in this forum but found no good solution.

Why this problem occurs and how to solve.

My program details are as follows

```
@Named("login")
@SessionScoped

public class Login implements Serializable {

    private String userId;
    private String password;

    @Inject
    private UserBeanLocal userBean;

    public Login() {
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String isValid(){

        if(userBean.getUser(userId).getPassword().equals(getPassword())) {
            return "home?faces-redirect=true";
        }        
        return "index?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

and the index.xhtml

```
<h:form>
                    <h:outputText class="title" value="Login"/><br/>
                    <h:inputText id="userId"                               
                                 value="#{login.userId}"                                 
                                 requiredMessage="User Id is required!" /><br />
                    <h:inputText id="password"                                
                                 value="#{login.password}"
                                 requiredMessage="Password is required!"/>

                    <h:commandButton id="submit"
                                     value="Submit"
                                     action="#{login.isValid()}"/>
                </h:form>
```

and the web.xml and beans.xml file is already there..

Comment: Have you by any chance overriden the bean inside your bean config file using another name? I believe that you can also omit that bracket () for isValid() in your action.

Comment: No. In fact I never touch beans.xml and it remains same from the very beginning. 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>

Comment: You might also want to look in you WEB-INF and see if the classes are really there and also check that your `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` are JSF 2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Did the CDI container boot properly? Please review your logs or try to inject an interface with no implementation and make sure that an exception is thrown.

Further if you have nothing defined in beans.xml then please remove everything in the file so that it's completely empty.

Remove the ("login") part of your `@Named` definition, it is superfluous to override with exact same value it would default to.

Make sure @SessionScoped is imported using the correct package. What you want is javax.enterprise.

Further answer the following questions:

1) What is your container?
2) Has CDI worked previously or is this your first try?
3) Describe the exact location of your beans.xml file.

Pasting your boot log from your servlet container would be helpful too (Tomcat, jboss whatever)